# How to run a function over certain observations?

Tags: r, lapply

I am trying to calculate the number of seats that parties won per district in a given election based on the number of votes they received in the district.

There is a function in R that will do this for each region:

```
seats_ha(party, votes, seats, method="dhondt")
```

The first argument provides a vector of party list names, the second argument provides a vector of the vote totals that each party won in a district, seats = the number of seats in a given district and the method is the electoral formula used to translate votes into seats. What I've been able to do is to calculate this by individually subsetting the data by a single region in an electoral year. My problem is that I have ~27 regions over 3 electoral years.

So my data look like this:

```
year   region dist_seat  party_name party_vote reg_id cong_id
2016-2021 AMAZONAS   2          UPP     0            1       3
2016-2021 AMAZONAS   2          FP      51067        1       3
2016-2021 AMAZONAS   2          AP      11992        1       3
2016-2021   ANCASH   5          FE       4534        2       3
2016-2021   ANCASH   5          UPP     0            2       3
```

I would like to be able to run the function for each region in each year.

Comment: See `dplyr::group_by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `by`, the object-oriented wrapper to `tapply` which slices a data frame by one or more columns to run needed operations. The input parameter to by's `FUN` is always a subsetted data frame and output will always be a list of whatever function returns, here being the return of `seat_ha`.

You can even add a new column to subsetted data frame and then `do.call` + `rbind` results for a single data frame. Below `tryCatch` ensures new column is always populated: actual result of `seats_ha` and `NA` if it encounters an error.

```
BUILD LIST OF SUBSETTED DFs
df_list <- by(mydata, mydata[,c("year", "region")], FUN=function(sub) {
                 # ADD NEW COLUMN TO sub DF
                 sub$calc_seat <- tryCatch(with(sub, seats_ha(party_name, party_vote, 
                                                              dist_seat, method="dhondt")), 
                                           error = function(e) NA)
                 return(sub)
             })

# ROW BIND ALL DFs
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Comment: I think this works perfectly! I was wondering if there would be a way for me to store the results in the same dataset as a new column of data?

Comment: See update now returning a data frame to be row-binded together outside.